# Why Telerik RadSlider is invisible in Chrome?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, telerik

I am using `Telerik` `RadSlider` inside `asp:Panel`

ASP

```
 <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="pueTags"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel>
        <telerik:RadSlider></telerik:RadSlider> 
    </asp:Panel>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void imgBtnTags_click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
   pueTags.show();
}
```

When I click on button Popup shows and RadSlider is working fine in IE and FF but in chrome it is invisible. [Here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/slider-control-not-visible-in-google-chrome) was the trick that **repaint** RadSlider on button click I tried the following code at button click it also worked fine in IE and FF but not in Chrome.

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="sliderPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</asp:Panel>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void imgBtnTags_click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    pueTags.show();

    RadSlider slider = new RadSlider();
    slider.ID = "sTagBookmark";
    slider.IsSelectionRangeEnabled = true;
    slider.OnClientSlideEnd = "resetButtons";
    slider.SelectionStart = 0;
    slider.SelectionEnd = 1;
    slider.MaximumValue = 100;
    slider.Width = 368;
    sliderPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(slider);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because the AjaxControlToolkit break the Telerik controls by overriding parts of the MS AJAX library: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/troubleshooting/general-troubleshooting#telerik-controls-are-incompatible-with-ajax-control-toolkit

Perhaps stopping the script combination of the toolkit script manager may help.

Another option: Look into throwing out the AjaxControlToolkit and use the RadWindow dialog from the Telerik suite.

As for the repaint() call, this should happen on the client-side, after the dialog is shown. Since the ModalPopupExtender does not expose client events nicely nor has documentation about them, perhaps your best shot is to register the script from the server and play with the timing, something like:

```
protected void imgBtnTags_click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    pueTags.show();
    string script = @"function f() {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $telerik.$('.RadSlider').each(function (index, elem) {{
                        if (elem && elem.control && elem.control.repaint)
                            elem.control.repaint();
                    });
                }, 500); /*play around with this timeout*/
                Sys.Application.remove_load(f);
            }; Sys.Application.add_load(f);";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "someKey", script, true);
}
```

Of course, the jQuery selector I use gets all sliders on the page and users their API through the DOM object properties. You can use $find() instead or tweak the selector to only repaint the desired slider.